# Data field not getting from the list

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

in my flutter code , i used a function to search the coupon code,

and it is fetching coupon document from firestore, and getting, as a list

i need only  disc_perc value to store Discount_amt variable

```
Future<void> CouponSearch(String couponCode) async {
    try {
      QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Coupons')
          .where('disc_code', isEqualTo: couponCode)
          .get();

      if (snapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        var couponData = snapshot.docs.first.data();

        **// in the below line have error,** 

         String discountAmt = couponData['disc_perc'].toString();

        print('coupon data: $couponData');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error fetching coupon data: $e');
    }
  }
```

and the coupn data prining
coupon data: {disc_perc: 10, proid: ResellerFotokad, disc_code: Fotokad}

Comment: check the type of "disc_perc" in the Firestore document is from type of int.

Comment: what's the error you getting?